# get type of std::shared_obj that it holds c++

Tags: c++, c++11, instanceof

My question is about testing an `std::shared_ptr` to see if it is a certain class type.

I am using a function called `instanceof` to test if I can perform a `std::static_pointer_cast<>`. The problem is that when passing an std::shared_ptr to my instanceof function it sees the shared_ptr as the type of the shared_ptr and not the actual type of the data the shared_ptr is holding.

*Class Hierarchy*

```
Object
   |
   --- Item
```

*Further explanation by example.*

```
// Type.h
template <class Base = Object, class Derived>
inline bool instanceof(const std::shared_ptr<Derived>&)
{
   return std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived>;
}

// ObjectDB.h
class ObjectDB
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Object> getObject(const char* obj_name);
}

// main.cpp

auto obj = gObjectDB.getObject("torch");
if (instanceof<Item>(obj))
{
    if (auto item = std::static_pointer_cast<Item>(obj))
    {

    }
}
```

In the example above `instanceof` becomes `instanceof<Item, Object>` which means instanceof will return false as it needs `instanceof<Item, Item>`. I have tried to use `instanceof<Item, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*obj)>>` as suggested by a couple of sources online but this still ends up being `instanceof<Item, Object>`

Comment: Why not use `dynamic_pointer_cast` and check if the resulting pointer is not a `nullptr`?

Comment: I want to stay away from dynamic casts. My program shouldn't need them the way I designed my classes

Comment: Unfortunately what you are attempting to do here with `instanceof` and the `static_cast` says you have not been successful at that design goal. You are reinventing `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: If you want to stay away from it, that's ok. But I don't see why a `std::static_pointer_cast` combined with `std::is_base_of` is any better. Essentially, `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` does exactly that for you.

Comment: @crazypeter you are right that `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` could work but it is expensive compared to doing a simple check if it can cast. the check if more to ensure human error does not mess with the program as the object name comes from an xml file

Comment: Your code makes all its decisions at compile time, based on static types of the entities involved. It cannot possibly give different answers depending on what happens at run-time. You need some form of `dynamic_cast` for that, as others already pointed out. `std::shared_ptr<Object>` has no idea whether the `Object*` pointer it holds actually points to an `Object` subobject of `Item`.

Comment: Have you considered avoiding this altogether and adding a `use` virtual function to `Item`? Then you could do something along the lines of `gObjectDB.getObject("torch").use();`, assuming a torch is present in the inventory list, and the implementation of `use` for a torch will be executed.